# MIPS Assignment with Poor Instruction

Tags: assembly, mips

[Screnshot of Assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpzoO.png)First year CS student, professor is not teaching at all. Can someone help me get started with the following assignment?

> Your first assignment is to write a MIPS assembly language program
> that runs on spim and prints a table of squares and cubes.  Your
> program will prompt the user for the maximum value in the table.  If
> the user enters the value 5, then your program will print the table:
> (table with squares and cubes of number).
>
> The control flow of your program should follow the code fragment:
>
> ```
>  for(i = 1; i <= max; i++)
>      printf("%d\t%d\n", i, i*i, i*i*i);
> ```

Would appreciate any and all help, thank you.

Comment: Decompose the problem into piece parts.  Solve each piece part.  Put the solved piece parts together for an overall solution.  So, given `for(i = 1; i <= max; i++) printf("%d\t%d\n", i, ii, ii*i);` decompose that into individual operations and control flow.  I count about a dozen piece parts for that.

Comment: You're taking an assembly course as a first year student?

Comment: What's the part you're stuck on? What specifically with the question confuses you? I mean, I'm confused personally how this is a first-year assignment myself, but basic problem solving rules still apply.

Comment: I don't even know where to start, yes this is supposed to be an intro course. He only went into the theory during lecture, but no mention as to how to actually write this code, what software to use, etc.

Comment: Do you already know how to program in some other language, like the C this assignment uses?  It's possible to learn about program logic in terms of asm first I guess, but you wouldn't do it with an assignment like this.

Comment: I know python and Java

Answer (score 1):

First, and most importantly, get working C code.  It is futile and frustrating to take broken C code to assembly.

What you have is broken in that:

- the `printf` only prints two items, yet takes three items beyond the format string, so that is a mistmatch
- <strike>there is no `ii` variable in the code snippet</strike>
- working C code means something you can compile & test run (lots of online C compilers/debuggers) — and a C compiler will only accept complete declarations, here that would be a whole functions with any needed variable or parameter declarations, not merely one line snippet of code with assumed variable declarations.

---

Once you have working C code, decompose the construct while remaining in the C programming language.

```
for ( i = 1; i <= max; i++ ) 
    printf ( "%d\t%d\n", i, i*i );
```

So, we can start decomposing almost anywhere — but let's start at the top, with the `for` loop.

A `for` loop can be converted into a `while` loop, which is simpler, and of course, this results in an expansion by a few lines:

```
i = 1;
while ( i <= max ) {
    printf ( "%d\t%d\n", i, i*i );
    i++;
}
```

The `while` construct is simpler than `for` as the initializer and increment are explicitly separated in this decomposition.

Next, turn the `while` loop into if-goto-label style of assembly.  This mechanical pattern transformation requires the introduction of labels.

```
    i = 1;
loop1:
    if ( i > max ) goto loop1Exit;
    printf ( "%d\t%d\n", i, i*i );
    i++;
    goto loop1;
loop1Exit:
```

The above is in if-goto-label form, which happens to also be valid C code.  Though still in C now we have much simpler lines of code for the control flow, and these can rather easily be translated to assembly.

However, next work on the `printf`.  How many things is it printing?  First, an integer, next a tab, then another integer, then a newline.  So, decompose the `printf` into those.

```
    i = 1;
loop1:
    if ( i > max ) goto loop1Exit;

    // printf ( "%d\t%d\n", i, i*i );

    printf ( "%d", i );
    printf ( "\t" );
    int temp = i*i;
    printf ( "%d", temp );
    printf ( "\n" );

    i++;
    goto loop1;
loop1Exit:
```

Each of those 4 simplified `printf`s can be done with one `syscall` on spim.

With its simple lines of code, the above decomposition, still C code, is ready to translate to assembly!

---

Starting with that decomposed but working C code, translate variables: pick physical storage locations for `i` and `max` — CPU registers are appropriate, just avoid `$a0` and `$v0`, as those will be needed for the `syscall`s, and that usage would wipe out any variables stored there.

After that most every line will translate to MIPS as a single instruction (simple `syscall`s generally take around 3 lines).

This approach is simple, logical, yet rather mechanical transformations to go from C code to simplified/decomposed C, then on to assembly code.  Decomposing the code while staying in C has some readability, testability, and instructional advantages.  (Btw, this decomposition would have resulted in the same simple code doing it in any order.)

Hopefully, you can see the baby steps, each a logical progression applying a well-known pattern transformation, that together complete decomposition.  It is a bit like working problems in math or proofs, where at each step we can apply some known rule, and by composing one step after another we get to the desired place.

Comment: There's no `ii` variable in the code snippet at all, and no reference to one.  There's no `plutonium` either...  Maybe you were just looking at the broken mess from lack of `code formatting` so markdown turned the `*`s into italics.  The format string is missing conversions for the last two args, so you're right that's a real bug.  Like they want you to compute but not print `i*i*i` :P

Comment: You forgot(?) to link the system call table for MARS or SPIM.  https://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html

Comment: I added a link to the screenshot for clarification.

Comment: Ok so I misunderstood the code as it was in markup, but hopefully you get the idea from this decomposition example.

Comment: Any recommendations for IDE or other software to use to write this?

Comment: I would go with MARS, as it has an IDE, whereas spim is more of an assembler/simulator.